# TALEND STUDIO - Get number of Non-working Days between start_date and end_date using TMAP in Talend

Tags: talend, tmap

I am a beginner in Talend and I need to achieve the following:

For example, I have two input tables in the TMAP component.

Table 1:

| Start_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- |
| 25/8/2022 | 1/9/2022 |

Table 2 (Lookup Table):

| Non_working_days | Remark |
| --- | --- |
| 27/8/2022 | Weekend |
| 28/8/2022 | Weekend |
| 31/8/2022 | Weekend |

I would want my output to count the number of non-working days from the lookup table.

For exp:

| Start_Date | End_Date | No_of_non_working_days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25/8/2022 | 1/9/2022 | 3 |

Can this be achieved by using the expression editor in the TMAP component or I will need to create a routine to achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is doable with a subjob , a bit complex but an interesting one :
[image]
Main idea: generate all dates between startDate and endDate, then compare each one of these dates to the content of table 2. Then count the number of corresponding dates.

- tFixedFlow1 (table 1) place here your input table 1
- tFlowToIterate : this will create global variables for startDate and endDate, that will be important for the next steps
- tLoop : the aim is to generate all dates contained between startDate and endDate
  See detail :
  [image]
- tIterateToFlow : once we have created all dates between start and endDate, regroupe the iterationFlow into a unique flow.
- tLogRow : just so you can control content.
- tMap+table 2 : join input flow with lookup from your table 2. Make it an innner join.
- tAggregate : count the number of lines in the output
- tLogRow : print screen of the result.

Comment: Which schema should I add to the tIteratetoFlow component?

Comment: add a column of type Date , put into it the date of your current iteration

Comment: sorry, please corect me if i am wrong, I tried added 
(java.util.Date)globalMap.get("tLoop_1_CURRENT_VALUE") 
to the date column however it returns null in the final results for all the dates. Am I getting it wrong?